# How do I upgrade from vSphere 4.1 to vSphere 5 without access to vSphere Update Manager?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have a small VMware lab setup at home that I use to test things out before work deployment. As part of this, I used the free VMware vSphere4 license. This does not include vCenter support.

Reading through the docs, it appears that the only listed upgrade path that I can find is by using the Update Manager.

Not having gone through a VMware upgrade before, I'm looking for options that will let me upgrade from 4.1 to 5 without having to resort to rebuilding the entire box.

Answer (score 4):

There's an upgrade option on 5.0's install CD, which can upgrade a 4.x host without blowing away settings and local data stores.  VMware has an article [here](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.upgrade.doc_50/GUID-FE668788-1F32-4CB2-845C-5547DD59EB48.html) covering the upgrade options.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it via command line. This requires that you have the patch available in a VMFS.

I just copied the patch zip over into a NFS datastore.

> esxcli software vib install -d
>   /vmfs/volumes/[DATASTORE]/[PATCH_FILE].zip

Credit for figuring this out goes to [this url](http://www.chriscolotti.us/vmware/vsphere/how-to-patch-vsphere-5-esxi-without-update-manager/).